# feature detection: translateZ

Tags: css, feature-detection

how can i find out if a browser supports translateZ or not?

i tried this one but it doesnt work...
https://gist.github.com/lorenzopolidori/3794226

i only changed translate3D to translateZ,
a short codepen example http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/NGpEZM?editors=101

```
el.style[t] = 'translateZ(100px)';
```

in IE10/11 i always get true... but as you see in the short example translateZ is not support in IE... because the typo is behind the black div

some ideas??

Comment: `translateZ` _is_ supported on IE10/11: http://caniuse.com/#search=translate and http://caniuse.com/#search=translate3d (apart from `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

Comment: ahh ok thank you this was my problem ;)

ok with another detection i got the correct answer, to find ou if preserve-3d is supported or not
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/762